# Elements of scattering theory for the Schrodinger operator

Tags: schroedinger-equation, scattering

I am learning about scattering and do not understand the following

> Informally speaking, the scattering describes the result of passing of
>   plane waves $\phi \sim e^{\pm i k x}$ through the field of the
>   potential $u(x)$, from $x = -\infty$ to $x = \infty$.

I do not understand what is meant by

> ... passing of the plane waves through the field of the potential $u(x)$

So, to my understanding, $u(x)$ is a function which describes the potential energy of the plane wave at the point $x$. What is... the *field* of potential?

Comment: Could you give a reference to your source? thanks!

Comment: The field of a potential is typically defined as $-\nabla u$.

Comment: The conceit is that the variation of the potential exerting a force on the incident wave and thereby influencing it to change to the outgoing wave is of limited extent ("field of force"). So the scattering occurs in a finite region of *x*, often around the origin, but at infinity the potential is constant and so immaterial.